# Excel VBA Clicking A Button on IE without ID

Tags: html, vba

I have been trying create a macro for automated data entry from Excel to a website. I need to click a button to create a new profile for the data, the following is the inspect code for the button.

```html
<input class="btn" onclick="addListNew();" type="button" value="ADD NEW">
```

I have searched around on google and tried using .queryselector, tagx, .click. These methods didn't work.

and the code I have been using

```
Set tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
  For Each tagx In tags
     If tagx.Value = "ADD NEW" Then
         tagx.Click
         Exit For
     End If
Next
```

```
doc.querySelector("[onclick='addListNew();']").Click
```

The querySelector one will return error code 91.

Comment: Is the element inside a parent iframe/frame? Do you need a longer wait before the click?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781861/cant-use-queryselector-in-a-proper-way-in-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this line:**

```
Set tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
```

**to:**

```
Set tags = doc.getElementsByClassName("btn")
```

That should make it work. Searching by Class Name instead of Tag name